# how do I get a list of dates from a date range using groovy

Tags: hibernate, groovy

I have a simple query which get a list of all dates in a date range, and want to implement it in groovy.

```
select 
TO_DATE('01/23/2012','MM/DD/YYYY') + level -1
from 
dual connect by level < (TO_DATE('02/07/2012','MM/DD/YYYY') - TO_DATE('01/23/2012','MM/DD/YYYY'));
```

Result set is :

```
23-JAN-12
24-JAN-12
25-JAN-12
26-JAN-12
27-JAN-12
28-JAN-12
29-JAN-12
30-JAN-12
31-JAN-12
01-FEB-12
02-FEB-12
03-FEB-12
04-FEB-12
05-FEB-12
```

Can I do this using groovy or if not hibernate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
d1 = new Date("1/23/2012")
d2 = new Date("2/5/2012")
(d1..d2).each { println "${it} (${it.format('dd-MMM-yy').toUpperCase()})" }
```

Outputs:

```
Mon Jan 23 00:00:00 EST 2012 (23-JAN-12)
Tue Jan 24 00:00:00 EST 2012 (24-JAN-12)
Wed Jan 25 00:00:00 EST 2012 (25-JAN-12)
Thu Jan 26 00:00:00 EST 2012 (26-JAN-12)
Fri Jan 27 00:00:00 EST 2012 (27-JAN-12)
Sat Jan 28 00:00:00 EST 2012 (28-JAN-12)
Sun Jan 29 00:00:00 EST 2012 (29-JAN-12)
Mon Jan 30 00:00:00 EST 2012 (30-JAN-12)
Tue Jan 31 00:00:00 EST 2012 (31-JAN-12)
Wed Feb 01 00:00:00 EST 2012 (01-FEB-12)
Thu Feb 02 00:00:00 EST 2012 (02-FEB-12)
Fri Feb 03 00:00:00 EST 2012 (03-FEB-12)
Sat Feb 04 00:00:00 EST 2012 (04-FEB-12)
Sun Feb 05 00:00:00 EST 2012 (05-FEB-12)
```

Comment: cool ..Thanks..! the final goal is my latest question on processing the nested list for generating graph data! :)